# Iam getting error when trying to install 'npm quick.db'

Tags: node.js, discord.js, quick.db

I want to install quick.db to work with discord.js,but get error when install `npm i quick.db` on **Windows**

```
> npm i quick.db
integer@3.0.1 install C:\Users\User\server\node_modules\integer
prebuild-install || npm run build-release

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=14.7.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)

integer@3.0.1 build-release C:\Users\User\server\node_modules\integer
node-gyp rebuild --release

if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 50, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 554, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 547, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 532, in gyp_main
    generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 2008, in GenerateOutput
    msvs_version)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1843, in _CreateProjectObjects
    guid = _GetGuidOfProject(proj_path, spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 910, in _GetGuidOfProject
    guid = guid or MSVSNew.MakeGuid(proj_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSNew.py", line 48, in MakeGuid
    d = hashlib.md5((str(seed) + str(name)).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest().upper()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\User\Documents\server\JavaScript\node_modules\integer
gyp ERR! node -v v14.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! integer@3.0.1 build-release: `node-gyp rebuild --release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the integer@3.0.1 build-release script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-14T19_01_29_062Z-debug.log
npm WARN javascript@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN javascript@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! integer@3.0.1 install: `prebuild-install || npm run build-release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the integer@3.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-14T19_01_29_560Z-debug.log
```

Comment: maybe this could be resolved by writing `npm i -g windows-build-tools`. I'm not a windows user but I know it has fixed the problem for some users

Comment: I installed it, but it didn’t work, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using nodejs v10.20.1 or later

Make sure you have node-gyp globally installed, including all of its dependencies. On Windows you may need to configure some things manually.

If you're using Windows, follow these steps. Do them in this order, and don't skip steps.

- Install the latest of node 10 or node 12.
- Start an Admin PowerShell: Right-click the start icon, then pick Windows PowerShell (Admin)
- Install both vs2015 and vs2017 libraries. Each line will take ~5-10 minutes.

```js
npm install --global --production --vs2015 --add-python-to-path windows-build-tools
npm install --global --production --add-python-to-path windows-build-tools node-gyp
```

- In your project, make sure you're not fighting with old build configurations. Delete both your %USERPROFILE%/.node-gyp and your project's node_modules directories.
- Set up %USERPROFILE%/.npmrc correctly:

```js
msvs_version=2015
python=python2.7
```

(where %USERPROFILE% is your home directory).

- Run

```
npm i quick.db
```